# What are common Exception and how to solve them

Tags: android, exception

I have to give a `crash course of android` to some internees. One of them ask me the common exception and their reason. So i decided to ask it for new developer as well as for myself.

for example

A `NullPointerException` is thrown at `runtime` whenever your program attempts to use a `null` as if it was a real reference. For example, if you write this:

```
String foo = null;
int length = foo.length(); // it is nullPointerException ..
```

**What are other common exceptions occur in Android?**

Answer (score 0):

There are decades of common exceptions in Android. Read this documentation page http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html. Some are more common than others, but it strictly depends on what you develop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is often not understood and very common on this site to be asked questions about. It is also specific for Android. It is thrown when the applications tries to do network activity on the UI thread.

Another common Exception is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which is thrown when one tries to access an element of the array which does not exist.